# Best place to populate child records using ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net, repository

Where is it best to bring back the main record together with its child records? Repository or service? All in one method or in separate methods? This has been bothering me now for some time and I would be greatful if I can get this clarified. I am using old school `ADO.NET` and `stored procedures`. My scenario is that of a `book` with multiple `authors`.

My domain models for `book` and `author` are defined like this:

```
public class Book
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Title { get; set; }

     public List<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

A book can have multiple authors, hence the list:

```
public List<Author> Authors { get; set; }
```

I currently have a service layer method that calls a repository layer method to bring back book details.

My `book repository` is defined like this:

```
public async Task<Book> GetByBookIdAsync(int bookId)
{
     string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Db"].ConnectionString;

     using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
          await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();

          using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Books_GetByBookId", sqlConnection))
          {
               sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BookId", bookId));

               using (SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = await sqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync())
               {
                    Book book = null;

                    if (await sqlDataReader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                         book = new Book();
                         book.Id = bookId;
                         book.Title = sqlDataReader.GetFieldValue<string>(4);
                    }

                    return book;
               }
          }
     }
}
```

I call this method from my book service layer like this:

```
public async Task<BookDTO> GetByBookIdAsync(int bookId)
{
     BookDTO bookDTO = null;
     Book book = await bookRepository.GetByBookIdAsync(bookId);
     if (book != null)
     {
          bookDTO = new BookDTO();
          bookDTO.Id = book.Id;
          bookDTO.Title = book.Title;
     }

     return bookDTO;
}
```

My service layers returns `DTO` objects of book.

Where do I populate the list of authors? In my book's repository method or in my book's service layer method? My gut tells me in the book's repository method, but the easiest is probably in the service method? I can make a call to the book's repository to get the book details and make another call to the author repository to get a list of authors by book. If done this way then it is not needed to have an authors list in my book's domain model (it is never used) because I can now directly populate a book DTO object with it's list of author DTO objects?

My `book DTO` object looks like this:

```
public class BookDTO
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Title { get; set; }

     public List<AuthorDTO> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

I hope someone can help clarify this for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer your last idea. Use one repository for each entity, load them separately in the service and let the service link them together. That's a clear design with clear responsibilities.

However, I could imagine 2 scenarios where that pattern isn't appropriated:

1. If performance matters - If you have to increase performance, it may be better to load multiple types of entities with one procedure call. That may be a reason to load the book and all its authors together.
2. If author is not used as separate entity anywhere else. If the list of authors is just something like a 'list property' of the book entity, the book and it's authors may be loaded together so that the author repository is not needed anymore.

Comment: Ja but then I would have to remove the author list in the book domain model. Ideally I would like to populate the `whole` model with dependencies by the time the service is reached.

Comment: Yes, the author list in the book domain mode can be removed than. What does you mean with 'by the time the service is reached'?

Comment: What I mean is when the service method calls the repository to get the book, I would ideally like to load all data when the book is returned to the service. Do all the calls in the repository, book and author.